# How to set username and password for Chrome Proxy Using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm using webdriver.chrome.driver

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("0.0.0.0:1234");
capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
```

And it worked great before, but now I'm tested behind a proxy server that requires authentication. How do I pass chrome the username / password the proxy requires?

I can't find anything in the docs :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after much research I've learned that this is pretty much a limitation that a lot of people are working around by using a chrome extension that automatically puts in the proxy password as it pops up.

I chose not to go down this route and switched my proxy to IP based authentication.

Hope this helps someone else.