# I need to fix my proxy code ( Proxy = ip:port:username:password)

Tags: python

```
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from pathlib import Path
from re import search
from xml.dom.minidom import Element
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import os
import random



    file=open('proxy.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
    proxies = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    
    while True:
        PROXY = random.choice(proxies).replace('\n','')
        print('Current Proxy:',PROXY)
        chrome_options = Options()   
        chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(Path,options=chrome_options)
```

It only receives proxies in the form of ip:port. How can I integrate this into chrome as ip:port:username:password?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set username and password for Chrome Proxy Using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629460/how-to-set-username-and-password-for-chrome-proxy-using-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

You can't from the command line.  This is not available in chrome out of security considerations.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/net/docs/proxy.md#proxy-credentials-in-manual-proxy-settings

You can try injecting them in the HTTP requests via basic auth or possibly through some browser extension.  Also see

[How to set username and password for Chrome Proxy Using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629460/how-to-set-username-and-password-for-chrome-proxy-using-selenium)